# Providing an argument that looks like an option (rails runner / OptionParser / optparse)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, optionparser

I have a script `magic` which uses `rails runner` to invoke another script `magic-foo.rb`, which does it's own option parsing. Something like this:

```
exec("#rails", "runner", "#{some_path}/bin/magic-foo.rb", *arguments)
```

I want to expose the `--help` option from `magic-foo.rb` through `magic`, but `rails runner` consumes `--help` and dies with its own help message.

How can I get an argument that *looks* like an option through the use of `OptionParser` in `runner.rb`? Alternativel, how else can I get `magic` to evaluate `magic-foo.rb` in the right rails context with the right arguments?

Because an argument `--` is the standard way to say "don't process following arguments" I might expect an invocation like this to work: `rails runner .../magic-foo.rb -- [ARGS]`. Unfortunately it does not.

---

Active version of rails runner: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/880371ef2b4a2cb08f0c36ceba1eee41836bb739/railties/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb .